# Evento enter En Vue.js con Element UI

Tags: vue.js, elementui

Hola estoy teniendo un problema con el evento Keyup y otras formas de este, yo uso vue.js con element ui. El problema es que necesito que cuando se de enter se dispare cierta funcion.

```
<el-form-item label="Password" prop="password">
     <el-input show-password v-model="form.password" prop="password" ref="password" @keyup.enter="loginAction"></el-input>
</el-form-item>
```

El @Keyup no se dispara ni de la forma @keyup.13.
Hay alguna solucion para esto? o simplemente no se puede con Vue.js con Element UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te adjunto posibles soluciones, espero que te ayuden.

Trata de usar (si es posible en tu proyecto) @keyup.native.enter
A veces en Vue.js a la hora de trabajar con componentes personalizados (Element UI en este casp) los eventos nativos del DOM no se disparan correctamente. Por eso te recomiendo usar el modificar **.native** para escuchar estos eventos.

```
<el-form-item label="Password" prop="password">
 <el-input show-password v-model="form.password" prop="password" ref="password" @keyup.native.enter="loginAction">
</el-input>
```

También he visto soluciones a problemas semejantes que usan **@keydown.enter** en lugar de **@keyup.enter**

```
<el-form-item label="Password" prop="password">
 <el-input show-password v-model="form.password" prop="password" ref="password" @keydown.enter="loginAction">
</el-input>
```

Espero que te sean de utilidad estas soluciones.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!! El @keyup.native.enter="loginAction('form')" funciona perfectamente!